# C# caching and async requests

Tags: c#, caching, iis, asynchronous, async-await

In this method:

```
private async List<stuff> GetData()
{
    return await _appCache.GetAsync("SiteStructurePages",
         () => _repository.GetSomeStuff());
}
```

is there any reason to keep it async? My code will execute in async manner just once, and all subsequent requests will use cache. Async spreads up to other parts of my application, that doesn't hit database, because lots of stuff is cached.

Edit:
My application is IIS website application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any reason to keep it async?

That really depends on you. If you actually need to take advantage of asynchronous operations, which is **being able to scale**, then do keep it. Otherwise, if you don't,  use a synchronous API. it's all up to you and what you actually make use of in your code base.

I understand the fact that you're worried about async methods going "all the way" and actually altering your entire code-base to become async. That's why you should do it as long as it's worth it.

Side note - you can slightly modify your code to save yourself the async state-machine generation:

```
private Task<List<stuff>> GetData()
{
    return _appCache.GetAsync("SiteStructurePages",
         () => _repository.GetSomeStuff());
}
```

Comment: So I undestand, that in my case it doesn't help with scaling (async method will run like 0.001‰ of all cases) and I should make it sync.
``
Also I can't really remove async from that method, because result is instantly consumed.

Comment: @user2029276 Why does the fact that the result is instanstly consumed have anything to do with what I said?

Answer (score 0):

If you can ensure that the call is quick and that it's not going to block a UI thread, then sure, you don't need Async on this one.

However, if such things are not in your control, then I would leave it asynchronous.

Comment: My app is website, and I don't care if first request will be a bit longer.